# Microsoft Outlook 2010 Forgets Login Details

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Microsoft Outlook is running in the background and constantly pops up the following dialog:

[image: Login Details]

Even when checking the check box it does not persist! I am using a POP account and not Microsoft Exchange.

How can this be resolved?

(Login details are correct. Changed for screenshot)

Comment: Btw, even though you blacked out the server name and anonymized the user name, the full account name is still visible in the title of the dialog.

Comment: Well spotted, my bad! :-)

Comment: It's still visible in the edits - maybe ask a moderator to remove the old image.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible options to fix this issue:

First is to disable *Outlook Anywhere* feature, but then you will loose the ability to use your Outlook account outside of your corporate network. Anyway, to disable *Outlook Anywhere* you should go *File* → *Account Settings...* → (select your account) → *Change...* → *More Settings...* → Select *Connection* tab and uncheck the *Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP* option → *Apply*.

Another option is to choose Basic Authentification for the Exchange Proxy. Here is how to do this: go *File* → *Account Settings...* → (select your account) → *Change...* → *More Settings...* → Select *Connection* tab → *Exchange Proxy Settings...* → and in *Proxy authentification settings* choose *Basic Authentification* → *Ok* → *Apply*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is however happening with a POP account.